# Conditional probability cards non-replacement

Tags: probability

A standard deck of 52 cards is shuffled and two cards are drawn without replacement. What is the probability that the second card drawn is a queen if the first card drawn was a heart?

I can apply the conditional probability formula here right?

$p(h) = \frac{13}{52}$

$p(h ∩ q)  = \frac{1}{52}$

So $p(q|h)   = p(h ∩ q)/ p(h)$?

but I am a bit unsure about this, since I am not considering the "without replacement" part in the conditional probability equation.

But I also cannot do the following right:

$p(q|h)  \not= \frac{4}{51} \times \frac{13}{52}$

this would mean getting queens and hearts right?

Comment: Probability of queen equals probability of jack equals probability of king equals ..., so they must each be $1/13$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of selecting a Heart $P(H) = \frac{13}{52}$

Probability of selecting  Heart and Queen  $P(H ∩ Q)  = \frac{1}{52}$

Probability of selecting Queen if the first one was Heart $P(Q|H)   = P(H ∩ Q)/ P(H)=\frac {\frac{1}{52}}{\frac{13}{52}}=\frac{1}{13} $?

OR

If the first one is Heart then for the second draw, number of elements of sample space will be $13$ (Number of Hearts)

There is only one Queen Heart then Probability is  $P(Q|H)=\frac{1}{13}$